# google chrome extension : how to open a new browser window more than once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension opens a new browser window with this simple JS:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var room = new Date().getTime();
  win = window.open("http://www.example.com/page.html#"+room,"win","width=485,height=55");
});
```

This works great, but just once.

Second time I click, it just put the focus on the window but URL does not change at all.

I also tried this (with no success):

```
win.location = "http://www.example.com/page.html#"+room;
win.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.open()` is a generic JavaScript function; <del>Chrome rate-limits it so that malicious pages can't spawn many windows.</del>

There is a concept of a "window name" with [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Since  you're reusing the same one, it's not opening a new window. And the above rate-limiting still can apply.

However, as an extension, you have access to unrestricted tools.

Namely, take a look at [`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) and [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) APIs.

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "fullyQualifiedURLHere"});
```

Note that `create`/`update` methods do not require special permissions.

Comment: Looks like a CLUE. Now it opens new window all the time with chrome.windows.create